# socket.io react/node how do i update the connections without the current one?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to implement socket.io for basic chat messaging.
What I'm trying to do, is to update client in real time, with socket connections,
following an example:
`client one - logged in as x, client two - logged in as y.`
therefor,
client one should see y in it's online connections list, after client two logged,
but it can not see itself in the list. so it cant "chat" with itself.
same idea goes for client two, should see x in the list since its already logged in,
meaning 2 clients online, which should be:
`client one - list [y]`,
`client tow - list [x]`

The problem here, is after second connection, both client see x, and if i refresh the second client page, both clients will see y. which is not what I want.

the chat messaging hasn't implemented yet.
What I've been struggled with, is to update both clients in real-time for such scenario.
any idea what am I missing ?

server:

```
// Server
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_ADDRESS,
    methods: ['*'],
  },
});

const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT;

app.use(cors());

const connections = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(`User ${socket.id} connected`);

  socket.on("store_user", (data) => {
    connections[socket.id] = {
        userName: data.userName,
        socket: socket,
      };
    
    const onlineUsers = Object.values(connections)
    .filter((user) => user.socket.id !== socket.id) 
    .map((user) => user.userName);
    
    socket.emit('get_users', onlineUsers); // Send the list only to the current user.
    socket.broadcast.emit('get_users', onlineUsers); //update everyone with the changes. 

  })

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`User disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
    delete connections[socket.id];

    const onlineUsers = Object.values(connections).map((user) => user.userName);
    io.emit('get_users', onlineUsers); 

  })


});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

client:
Login Page:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const setUserName = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("userName", input);
        navigate('/chat')
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setInput(e.target.value)}}/>
        <button onClick={setUserName}>login</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

client:
Chat Page:

```
// Client
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const serverURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';
const socket = io.connect(serverURL);

const Chat = () => {
  const sessionUserName = sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDisconnect = () => {
      console.log('Disconnected');
    };

    const handleGetUsers = (data) => {
      setUsers(data);
    };

    socket.on('disconnect', handleDisconnect);
    socket.emit('store_user', { userName: sessionUserName });
    socket.on('get_users', handleGetUsers);

  }, [sessionUserName, socket]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(users)}>Show users</button>
      <ul>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <li key={user}>{user}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able so solve it.
first, I've created an array outside of socket instance to store all online users in backend,
might not be ideal for some scenarios, but for what I want, it's close enough in backend.
then i used filter to return a list of online users without the current one.

code:
backend:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const socketAuth = require('../middlewares/socketAuth');


const initSocket = (server) => {
  const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
      methods: ['*'], // can be change to => methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      credentials: true,
    },
  });

  let onlineUsers = [];

  io.use(socketAuth);


  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const userName = socket.handshake.query.userName;
    console.log(`user: ${userName} conntected, socketId: ${socket.id}`);
    onlineUsers.push({ socketId: socket.id, userName: userName });
    


    //manage online users
    //-----------------------------//
    //emit users without the current one..
    const filteredOnlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter((user) => 
    user.socketId !== socket.id)
    io.emit("getOnlineUsers", filteredOnlineUsers);
    //-----------------------------//



    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log(`user ${socket.id} disconnected.`);
      onlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter(user => user.socketId !== 
      socket.id);
    });

  });

  return io;
};

module.exports = initSocket;
```

then in client, i just simply called the event and loaded it into a state,
Note: this is just a partial code, i'm just sharing the concepts of my answer..

```
import {socket} from '../configs/socket'

useEffect(() => {
    if(isLoggedIn && userName){
      //send userName to server to store alongside the 
      //current socket.id connection.
      socket.io.opts.query = {userName};
      socket.connect();
    }

    socket.on("getOnlineUsers", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });


    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  },[isLoggedIn, userName]);
```

and if you're curios about how i've done my config to the socket in client:
im using cookies as well, therefor "withCredentials"..

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
const URL = 'yourbackendURL'

export const socket = io(yourbackendURL, {
    autoConnect: false,
    withCredentials: true
});
```